# java arrays.sort gives the same result regardless of comparable function in gui based sorter

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, user-interface, arraylist

I'm trying to write a program that allows me to compare pairs of images such that in the end they are sorted. In order to do this I implemented a gui based sorter, problem is that no matter what my comparable function returns the final sort is exactly the same.

This is my sort comparable function

```
public class img implements Comparable<img>{

    public int compareTo(img other) {


        CompareGUI gui = new CompareGUI(this,(img)other);
        while(gui.res==0)
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        System.out.println(gui.res);
        //return -1 //return 1
        return gui.res;
    }
```

If I insert return -1 or return 1 in there the results do not change, this function prints out 1 or -1 but the final result is always the same.

Here is how I use it:

```
public class Sorter {

    static String loc="~/Desktop";
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {

        ArrayList<img> images = loadImages();
        Arrays.sort(images.toArray());      
        for(int i=0;i<images.size();i++){
            images.get(i).rank=i;
        }
        tocsv(images);


    }

    //output function unlikely to be the issue
    public static void tocsv(List<img> images) throws IOException {
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(loc+"evalres.txt"));
        for(img im : images) {
            String str= im.rank+",\t";
            for(Integer t:im.values) {
                str=str+t+",\t";
            }
            str.substring(0, str.length()-2);
            str=str+'\n';
            writer.write(str);
        }
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();

    }
    //loading, also not the issue
    public static ArrayList<img> loadImages() {
        File dir = new File (loc);
        ArrayList<img> ret= new ArrayList<img>();
        for (File i  :dir.listFiles()) {
            if (i.getName().endsWith("png")){
                    ret.add(new img(i.getAbsolutePath()));
            }
        }
        return ret;

    }
}
```

The other two classes look as following(unlikely to contain the issue as just returning -1 or 1 in the compareto code bypasses this code and the behavior remains the same):

```
public class img implements Comparable<img>{


    int rank;
    List<Integer> values= new ArrayList<Integer>();




    String path;
    public img(String path) {
        this.path=path;
        readName(new File(path).getName());

    }
    private void readName(String str) {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(str);

        String[] words = str.split("[^0-9']+");
        for (String word : words) {
            if(!word.isEmpty())
            values.add(Integer.parseInt(word));
        }


    }


    @Override
    public int compareTo(img other) {


        CompareGUI gui = new CompareGUI(this,(img)other);
        while(gui.res==0)
            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        System.out.println(gui.res);
        return gui.res;
    }
}


public class CompareGUI extends JFrame{

    int res=0;
    JFrame frame;

    public CompareGUI(img ima, img imb) {
        frame=this;
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,2));
        Container cp = getContentPane();
        ImageIcon icoa=new ImageIcon(ima.path);
        ImageIcon icob=new ImageIcon(imb.path);

        JButton labela = new JButton(icoa);
        JButton labelb = new JButton(icob);
        labela.setSize(icoa.getIconWidth(), icoa.getIconHeight());
        labelb.setSize(icoa.getIconWidth(), icoa.getIconHeight());
        labela.setLocation(0, 0);
        labelb.setLocation(icoa.getIconWidth(), 0);

        cp.add(labela);
        cp.add(labelb);


        labela.setVisible(true);
        labelb.setVisible(true);
        this.setSize(icoa.getIconWidth()*2+50,icoa.getIconHeight()+50);
        this.setVisible(true);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        labela.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                res=-1;
                frame.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(frame, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
            }
        });

        labelb.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                res=1;
                frame.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(frame, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
            }
        });


    }


}
```

now no matter what images I click or how I modify the final result the same images are always sorted in exactly the same way which suggests to me that the result of the compareTo function are being ignored by the line         `Arrays.sort(images.toArray());`. Anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I simply cannot find what's wrong so if anybody has any questions please ask them so I can clarify.

Comment: you have some thread inside the compare?? thats pretty fancy junk

Comment: @gpasch Thread management in the compare works via the GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you are sorting the array (constructed from original collection); but expecting the original collection to be sorted.

So, Instead of `Arrays.sort(images.toArray());` use `Collection.sort(images)`, so that `images` is sorted

Comment: That is one of the issues with OP code. But there is a bigger mess with `compareTo` method.

Comment: ah that seems to be the issue, thanks. I now feel stupid. @tsolakp the problem with the compareTo code is probably that I have to somehow wait for the GUI to respond as it calls on the actual user to do the sorting

Comment: @Thijser. Thats not how you implement `compareTo`.

Comment: @tsolakp after this (pretty obvious in hindsight) fix it now works, how would you implement a compareTo that requires user input? What's the proper software engineering things to do here?

Comment: @Thijser. Inside your `mouseClicked` do: 1) Get user input. In your case it is the new value of `res`. 2) Create `comparotor` based on that input. 3) Sort your list using that comparator.

Comment: @tsolakp  How would I know what images to compare against each other before calling the sort function?

Comment: @Thijser. That is the logic you have to figure out. It has nothing to do with comparing. You need to gather enough information from user to be able to compare two given images.

Comment: @tsolakp which I figured out by first calling the sort function which calls the compareto function which gathers data from the user. It's not a fast way of sorting but when two classes require human interaction in order to sort why not let the compareto function spawn a gui which will need to be polled for the correct answer?